# Auto scrolling GtkScrolledWindow with GtkTextView wrapped in GtkBox

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

When I have GtkTextView in GtkScrolledWindow, it scrolls automatically when user appends new line at the bottom of the widget. When I put GtkTextView in GtkBox and then in GtkScrolledWindow I doesn't work. I need to put box between GtkTextView and scrollbar and I can't do that without placing whole thing in another box. Is there any way to preserve autoscrolling behaviour when using GtkBox inside GtkScrolledWindow?

There is code that ilustrates my problem:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),
        gdk_screen_width()*0.5, gdk_screen_height()*0.5); 

    GtkWidget *main = gtk_box_new(0, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), main);
    /*/////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    /* IMPORTANT PART */

    /* FIRST CASE (this one works correctly) */
    GtkWidget *scrolled_window_first = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    GtkWidget *text_view_first = gtk_text_view_new();

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window_first), text_view_first);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(main), scrolled_window_first, 1, 1, 0);

    /* SECOND CASE (there is no auto scroll which I need) */
    GtkWidget *scrolled_window_second = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    GtkWidget *text_view_second = gtk_text_view_new();
    GtkWidget *box_from_second_example = gtk_box_new(0, 0);
    GtkWidget *example_box_before_scroller = gtk_box_new(0,0);

    GtkWidget *example_label = gtk_label_new("I need this box badly!");

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box_from_second_example), text_view_second, 1, 1, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window_second), box_from_second_example);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box_from_second_example), example_box_before_scroller);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(main), scrolled_window_second, 1, 1, 0);

    /* END IMPORTANT PART */

    /*/////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(example_box_before_scroller), example_label);
    g_signal_connect(GTK_WINDOW(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `GtkTextView` implements `GtkScrollable` but `GtkBox` does not. This is not a minor issue: if you want to go the `GtkBox` way you should put it inside a [`GtkViewport`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkViewport.html) and add the scrollability stuff... quite some code that involves deep understanding of how the whole thing scrolls.

Anyway if you are lazy enough you could also note `GtkTextview` is a `GtkContainer`. In other words you could add widgets around the `GtkTextview` without the need to incomodate `GtkBox`. Not exactly what you were looking for but maybe good enough for your purposes:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>                                                    

gint main(gint argc, gchar **argv)                                      
{                                                                       
    GtkWidget *window, *scrolled_window, *text_view, *label;            

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);                                             

    text_view = gtk_text_view_new();                                    
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(text_view)),
                             "1\n\n\n2\n\n\n3\n\n\n4\n\n\n5\n\n\n6\n\n\n7\n\n\n8", -1);
    /* Use this to set the size you want to reserve on the right */     
    gtk_text_view_set_border_window_size(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(text_view),      
                                         GTK_TEXT_WINDOW_RIGHT,         
                                         130);                          
    /* Add whatever you want instead of a GtkLabel */                   
    gtk_text_view_add_child_in_window(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(text_view),         
                                      gtk_label_new("You badly need this"),
                                      GTK_TEXT_WINDOW_RIGHT,            
                                      0, 0);                            

    scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);              
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(scrolled_window), text_view);       

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);                       
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 320, 240);                                                                                                         
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), scrolled_window);          
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);                                        

    gtk_main ();                                                        

    return 0;                                                           
}
```

Comment: This is nasty... and the added widget does not honour scrolling but stays at x=0,y=0 ...

Comment: Actually I even like this behaviour. Maybe that's not the better option but it's easier and sufficient in my case. Thanks for help guys.

Comment: I found out that if you place box or any scrollable element inside, it scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to modify the `GtkAdjustment`s the textview creates by default (`GtkScrolledWindow` implements the `GtkScrollable` afaik).

```
GtkAdjustment *     gtk_scrollable_get_hadjustment      (GtkScrollable *scrollable);
```

I think the best approach would be to detect insertions to the `GtkTextBuffer` (get the views buffer via

```
GtkTextBuffer *     gtk_text_view_get_buffer            (GtkTextView *text_view);
```

and hook a callback (which tests for `\n`) to its `insert-text` g_signal and use

```
void             gtk_adjustment_set_value            (GtkAdjustment *adjustment,
                                                      gdouble value);
```

to modify the scrolling height.

Note that this is untested and a simpler method might be around the corner.